# recommended , suggests, mandatory

Tags: sentence-meaning

> The tribunal recommends that the dept reassesses the appellant within 18 months.

Is this obligatory, a suggestion or  mandatory?

Is the department obligated to reassess within the limited time?

Or is it just a suggestion and the department can reassess anytime, even after 6 years?

Answer (score 1):

A recommendation is a suggestion. Unlike an order or direction, it does not have to be obeyed. If a court (tribunal) decides that something must be done, and has the power to require it, then it issues an order. Failure to comply could lead to a penalty. If the court has no power to issue an order, or does not wish to, it may make a recommendation, with which the recipients are free to comply or not.

> recommendation
>
> noun
>
> advice about what is the best thing to have or do

While we are not free to disregard an order, we can ignore advice.

[Recommendation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recommendation)

Comment: Technically this answer is correct; a recommendation does not carry legal force. It might carry very strong practical force, however. Depending on the circumstances it might not be wise for the department to ignore such a recommendation even though the department might be legally entitled to do so.

Comment: Two Comments One; a tribunal is not a court and does not have the same powers, However quote "recommendations should still be taken into account by the national courts, especially if the recommendation assists with interpretation of some European law. Nonetheless, it is not possible to have them reviewed nor to seek a preliminary ruling upon them". Two: this is regarding an appeal so the writer already knows they need to comply.

Answer (score -2):

> recommended , suggests, mandatory Is the department obligated to reassess within the limited time?
>
> or is it just a suggestion? & the department can reassess anytime after that recommended time frame. even if the reassessment is after 6 ;years of the time
>    frame?

---

Unfortunately due to comments I have had to add more and more technical detail, So to summarise before presenting my Answer.

The question references an appellant. The decision has therefore been made and appealed against and upheld. So **there is no doubt about the decision**. A tribunal is not a court but is a **legal institution** so the definition of Recommended is the legal one. **LEGAL DICTIONARY** It is also worth noting that in some Tribunals recommendations can only be made in favour of the claimant. So we are looking at the "Dept" as the receiver of the recommendation, which is the way it reads. The inclusion of a time limit suggests **the Recommendation is binding** or time limit would not be needed.

> Example *A memorandum of appeal shall be presented in the Form annexed to these rules by the **Appellant***

---

My Answer

***Obviously we have not been given all the facts***.

> According to C.E.D. the meaning of **recommended**; *suggested an action that should be done:*

So yes in a grammatical sense this needs to be complied with especially as it has been decided by a Tribunal

> **Legal;** Recommendation **Definition**: [Legal Dictionary](http://www.duhaime.org/LegalDictionary/R/Recommendation.aspx)
>   Advice or counsel which although presented as such, the recipient is free to take or leave, or **which may be binding in the context**.

In this case "The tribunal recommends that the dept reassesses the appellant within 18 months" must be the second legal definition " binding in the context" or the application of a time limit would be superfluous

To put a little more strongly and in layman's terms. You would have to be either very arrogant, ignorant or stupid to not comply with a Tribunal's recommendation. Especially after an appeal.

You will probably find it irrelevant anyway as most Tribunal recommendations usually end up in statute. It is interesting to read the EU's definition of Recommendations.

> recommendation [Free Legal](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/recommendation) **a form of Act of the EUROPEAN UNION** that has no binding force. It has been held that **recommendations should still be taken into account by the national courts**, especially if the recommendation assists with interpretation of some European law. Nonetheless, **it is not possible to have them reviewed nor to seek a preliminary ruling upon them**.

So here we have a recommendation that initially seems to have no power. However, it is fact extremely powerful. Courts should comply with the recommendation and the recommendation has no process of review or interpretation.

*However as stated earlier these comments are made without context*.

> **recommended** [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recommended) adjective suggested as being good or suitable for a particular job or purpose, or suggested as an action that should be done:
>
> **tribunal** noun [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tribunal?q=%20tribunal) a special court or group of people who are officially chosen, especially by the government, to examine (legal) problems of a particular type:

Comment: This answer is just silly. A recommendation is not an order. And tribunals offer recommendations all the time, for example, a recommendation to try voluntary arbitration. The answer reflects neither the meaning of the words inquired about nor familiairity with the practice of courts.

Comment: @Jeff Morrow. Really??? The recommendation is not to the appellant but to the department (therefore Recommended= polite instruction).The case applies to an appellant. So they have already appealed and been turned down. This is an ongoing dispute and they already know they must comply it has just been reconfirmed. Hence my comments.

Comment: Hmm. Every order I have seen from a court starts with something like "It is hereby ORDERED ..." There is not, and should not be, any possibility of ambiguity in a court order. Decisions are not rendered in language like "The court thinks it might be nice if ..."

Comment: Moreover, you are misreading the language. It is not the department that is the appelant. The department has already prevailed below. This is a court not over-ruling the department, but suggesting that the department reconsider. Who is "they" in your comment?

Comment: @ I am correct the recommendation is to the department to reassess the appellant. 2 A Tribunal is not a court. How is an administrative tribunal different from a court?  Although administrative tribunals may resemble courts because they make decisions about disputes, they are not part of the court system.

Comment: @Jeff Morrow: Why do you keep referring to courts there is no reference to a court it is a tribunal.

Comment: According to Merriam-Webster, a "tribunal" is a "court or furum of justice." What do you think the definition of "tribunal" is? Any citations? Or is this similar to the case where your definition of "recommendation" is "order."

Comment: @Jeff Morrow As already commented https://www.adminlawbc.ca/what-is-admin-law/tribunals-vs-courts;  How is an administrative tribunal different from a court? Although administrative tribunals may resemble courts because they make decisions about disputes, they are not part of the court system.